# can't install github windows 7 (error)

Tags: github

i get this error:

PLATFORM VERSION INFO
    Windows             : 6.1.7601.65536 (Win32NT)
    Common Language Runtime     : 4.0.30319.42000
    System.Deployment.dll       : 4.6.1055.0 built by: NETFXREL2
    clr.dll             : 4.6.1076.0 built by: NETFXREL3STAGE
    dfdll.dll           : 4.6.1055.0 built by: NETFXREL2
    dfshim.dll          : 4.0.41209.0 (Main.041209-0000)

IDENTITIES
    Deployment Identity     : GitHub.application, Version=3.1.1.4, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=317444273a93ac29, processorArchitecture=x86

APPLICATION SUMMARY
    * Installable application.
    * Trust url parameter is set.
ERROR SUMMARY
    Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
    resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
        + Specified cast is not valid.

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION FAILURE SUMMARY
    No transaction error was detected.

WARNINGS
    There were no warnings during this operation.

OPERATION PROGRESS STATUS
    * [5/25/2016 5:40:53 PM] : Activation of 
    * [5/25/2016 5:40:56 PM] : Processing of deployment manifest has successfully completed.
    * [5/25/2016 5:40:56 PM] : Installation of the application has started.

ERROR DETAILS
    Following errors were detected during this operation.
    * [5/25/2016 5:40:59 PM] System.InvalidCastException
        - Specified cast is not valid.
        - Source: System.Deployment
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.VerifyRequestedPrivilegesSupport(String requestedExecutionLevel)
            at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadApplicationManifest(AssemblyManifest deploymentManifest, String targetDir, Uri deploymentUri, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options, Uri& appSourceUri, String& appManifestPath)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.DownloadApplication(SubscriptionState subState, ActivationDescription actDesc, Int64 transactionId, TempDirectory& downloadTemp)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.InstallApplication(SubscriptionState& subState, ActivationDescription actDesc)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION DETAILS
    No transaction information is available.

Comment: Is it possible that your download was corrupted in anyway?

Comment: @ELI Sadoff no I don't think so

Comment: What it looks like might have happened looking at the trace is that something happened when the installer was downloading data. Try re-installing and see if you get the same error.

Comment: yes i got the same error

Comment: I'm not sure how to help you. Sorry. I'd try reaching out to github support.